Is the Atomic packing factor for a body centered tetragonal crystal structure the same as one for a body centered cubic crystal structure?
If not, what is the Atomic packing factor (percentage) for a body centered tetragonal crystal structure?

It depends on the objects you put in the cell (ellipsoids?).

@Karsten An atom would never be an ellipsoid, right? This is what led me to believe that the atomic packing factor had to be different because that means there has to be extra space.

A molecule such as N2 is like an ellipsoid. Or you could have covalent bonds along a layer and Van der Waals across layers, like in graphite. Anyway, it depends on the shape of the repeating object, and the definition of empty vs filled space.

For protein crystals, the term solvent content is used.

I think you are confusing two separate concepts, the crystal structure (i.e. the shape of the cell) and what you put in the cell (called the basis). A given crystal structure can have many different bases, and each can have different filling fractions.

"An atom would never be an ellipsoid, right?" Wrong. Consider a hexagonally close-packed structure of spheres. We calculate geometrically that the $c/a$ ratio should be $\sqrt{8/3}\approx 1.63$. Now look up the lattice constants of zinc, a hexagonly close-packed metal: $c/a\approx 1.86$! In the nonisotropic environment of the crystal the zinc atoms have become prolate (elongated on one axis) spheroids.

The packing factors are generally not the same for spherical atoms. In fact the body-centered tetragonal packing factor may be either greater or less than the body-centered cubic one.
In particular, if we design a body-centered tetragonal lattice with the unit cell having a square base of side $a$ and a tetragonal axis length $c=\sqrt2a$, we find that the lattice actually is face-centered cubic. For that case the packing factor is increased from approximately 0.68 for the body-centered cubic structure to about 0.74 common to varioys three-dimensional close-paced structures.

How would you go about determining if an atom is spherical or not? Also, is there a list of packing factors I can find for each of the elements?
